# How do I compare two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I compare two arrays, in size AND in content?

In the class with the constructor I created this `equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(VarArray otherArray) {
    if ((myInts.equals(otherArray)))) { 
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I have it in the class I'm testing with and I still get `false` instead of `true`:

```
int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

VarArray testArray = new VarArray(array);
VarArray testArray2 = new VarArray(array);

System.out.println("\n" + testArray.equals(testArray2)); // should be true
```

Comment: Your logic is just odd.  Why would you check myInts.equals and this.myInts.equals?  They're going to be the same.  Do you understand scoping in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`otherArray` is of type `VarArray` and you're comparing it to an array of `int`s. What you want is:

```
public boolean equals(VarArray otherArray) {
   return Arrays.equals(myInts, otherArray.myInts);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use `Arrays.equals(testArray, testArray2);`

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrays.deepEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) will perform deep comparison, which will also check for any nested elements.

```
public boolean equals(VarArray otherArray) {
    return Arrays.deepEquals(myInts, otherArray.getInts());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implmentaion of equals is wrong. In your case it will call the equals method of array which will compare the object instance of both the array which are different. Correct implementation of equals method will look like this:

```
public class VarArray
{

    private int[] myInts = null;

    private int[] getMyInts()
    {
        return myInts;
    }

    public VarArray(int[] arr)
    {
        myInts = arr;
    }

    public boolean equals(VarArray otherArray)
    {
        if (myInts == null && otherArray == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (myInts == null || otherArray == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (myInts.length != otherArray.getMyInts().length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int[] otherMyInts = otherArray.getMyInts();
        for (int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++)
        {
            if (myInts[i] != otherMyInts[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to write such code, which is in my opinion waste of time and energy use java.util.Arrays and use this code

```
int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] array1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
boolean isEqual = Arrays.equals(array, array1);
        System.out.println(isEqual);
```